# RabbitMQ in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, amqp

I want to take advice. So I am creating a micro service which which will fetch data from the db and send back to the website whenever a customer opens the home page. So would using RabbitMQ be beneficial in such a case. I am thinking of adding the RabbitMQ layer between the Frontend and the Controllers in the spring boot microservice. So that none of the requests are missed. 
Would it help in reducing the latency as I want a very low latent system

Comment: See if this answers https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html

Answer (score 1):

That would be a misuse of an message queues. Messages are used to delegate asynchronous actions, when you want something to be done (usually a long executing action), but You don't want to wait for the results. Or notify other services, that something has happened, but you are not sure if they are available or not.

Using MQ to fetch data into a webpage, would generate more problems that benefits.
Web applications, do not provide push mechanisms (without crawling or web sockets). Web page can only call for data from Server, data cannot be pushed to the web page from server itself.

**Proposed solution:**

If you want to display data from a **single datasource**, or a single join can provide all data, then simple spring boot MVC will do.

If you are using **multiple datasources** (eg. tables), then you could use benefits of an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) application. Return homepage with minimum layout. Then use multiple AJAX calls to fetch data from the database. This way user will call for all sources at the same time, and calls will not block each other.

If you want to go into microservices, you could write a node.js frontend app, that will fetch data from your spring-boot application, though REST api.

Your queues could be used to notify users about their task process, status change, etc, but for this you will have to use a web socket.

**UPDATE (message async example):**

User wants to generate a report - from all tables, and send it to a remote file storage (S3). 
From user perspactive it will be a simple button click. Because ation will be delegated to another service and executed asynchronously. User is only notified, that his action has been requested.
Your service will publish a message that will request this report to be made (by another or same service), then pushed to data file storage.

After the process is completed (even after few hours), new message is published to user serviece or email, saying that report has been completed.

So User could click genrate report button, and go home. He will receive an email notification, when everything is completed.

Comment: Can you give an example of this - Messages are used to delegate asynchronous actions, when you want something to be done (usually a long executing action), but You don't want to wait for the results.

Comment: So you are suggesting that front end hitting the Controller endpoints directly is the way to go for the above use case

Comment: Ad1. Like processing a large file, that will update multiple tables in the database. Ad2. Yes. With this approach you could create multiple services, providing data to your endpoint.

Comment: So suppose I get around 10k hits/sec on the website, then is there any way to optimise the normal approach which you mentioned. Or would it depend on how I optimise the db queries, basically optimisation within the service level methods which will fetch and send back data

Comment: If you have 10k calls a sec, then a single app will not be enough. You will need to scale it horizontaly - add more applications and a loadbalancer on the top. It will still be better than Message Queue. With this scane, a kubernetes/hive, AWS beanstock could help. As for the optimization - every step is important, like using Reactive approach, performing efficiend SQL querries., etc. This may be optimized in multiple ways.